# regex of extracting html from path

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to Regex.
I need to extract 2 things from a directory path.
../path_to_html/myhtmlpage.html?additional_args_or_url

how can i get the name of the html? 
eg.myhtmlpage

and how can i get the entire url?
eg.myhtmlpage.html?video_url=www.google.com/video

Thank you very much!

Comment: These are files on your local machine? or do you have a url that you want to parse?

Comment: can't you just search for the first occurance of .html? this way you know the url is between the last "\" before .html and goes to the end of the string

Comment: If you are new to regular expressions, the best thing you can do is sit down with some documentation and figure it out yourself.Having someone hand you a regular expression you don't understand won't server you well in the long term.

Comment: I know. I will look into documents later. I need to fix some code before an urgent meeting. The only thing that I have in my mind is stackoverflow. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import re
url = "/path_to_html/myhtmlpage.html?video_url=www.google.com/video"
# Name
print re.findall(r'/(\w+)\.html', url)[0]
# Entire url
print re.findall(r'/(\w+\.html.*)', url)[0]
```

This prints:

```
myhtmlpage
myhtmlpage.html?video_url=www.google.com/video
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Done. Sorry, I am new here : )